# In Batch, Why is it that "not ", ignores the "if else" command and runs the next code anyway?

Tags: batch-file

code:

```
echo To Start, type start
echo To view Options, type options
echo To Quit Game, type quit
set /p input= Command? 
if %input% == start goto Start
if %input% == options goto Options
if %input% == quit goto Exit
else (
goto Menu
)
```

Basically what it should do is typing one of those choices will go to that part of the code, and typing something that isn't specified will run that script again. This works as intended, but my problem is when I type "not blah" (without quotes, where blah could be anything) it runs the script despite there not being specified action for blah in the code.

Why?

Comment: maybe you need to quote the test `if "%input%" == "start" ...` because it is probably expanding to `if not blah == start` which may evaluate to true

Comment: You also don't need an `else` at all, just `goto Menu`. If the other lines are true, their `goto` will bypass all the ones below. If all the other lines evaluate to false, it will just hit the `goto Menu` automatically - the `else` is unnecessary.

Comment: The proper syntax for an IF ELSE command is clearly defined in the help file.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that you did not double quote your variables when comparing, you cannot use `else` like that. Else has to be on the same line as the closing parenthesis of the previous `if` statement and the opening parenthesis of the `else` code block. i.e: `) else (`

Anyway to eliminate the need to accommodate for user errors in typing commands just use `choice`:

```
@echo off
:menu
choice /c SOQ /M "[S]tart, [O]ptions, [Q]uit"
goto opt%errorlevel%

:opt1
Echo this is the start section
goto :eof

:opt2
echo this is the Options section
goto :eof

:opt3
echo This is the Quit section
exit

:opt0
Goto menu
```